# Get Column Data Type Using Active JDBC

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

How can I get column data types using Active JDBC ? Is It Possible?
I need data type for each column of my model for automation purposes.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC DatabaseMetaData.getColumns() returns duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601203/jdbc-databasemetadata-getcolumns-returns-duplicate-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  you can get that from a `MetaModel`:

```
MetaModel mm = person.getMetaModel();
Map<String, ColumnMetadata> cmMap = mm.getColumnMetadata(); 
ColumnMetadata cm = cmMap.get("first_name");
String typeName =  cm.getTypeName();
```