# command to fetch datatypes of fields in the table to store in resultset in oracle DB

Tags: database, jdbc, plsql, oracle11g

Using Oracle DB and JDBC to fetch the datatypes of the table to store in result set and then insert the values based on the datatypes.
Used the "Desc " to fetch datatype of the table but getting as invalid sql statement.

```
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement stmt = null;
String val = "";
String query = "desc EMS#CHANNELS";

Map<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
Connection conn = DBUtil.getOraDBConnection();
Logger.info("get the table desc="+query);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 3):

DESC is short for DESCRIBE.

DESCRIBE is not a database sql/plsql command or program.

It's a feature of SQL*Plus, which is a client application for interacting with the database.

The SQL equivalent would look something like this:

```
select COLUMN_NAME
      ,DATA_TYPE
      ,DATA_PRECISION
      ,DATA_SCALE
  from DBA_TAB_COLS -- DBA_ views are faster but require higher privs than ALL_ views
 where OWNER = 'HR'
   and TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEES'
 order by COLUMN_ID desc;
```

You might want to take a look at [oracle.jdbc
Class OracleDatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html)

Here's the JDBC Metadata in use to look up columns of a table :
   [JDBC DatabaseMetaData.getColumns() returns duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601203/jdbc-databasemetadata-getcolumns-returns-duplicate-columns)